# How to convert vertical data to horizontal dynamically without using Cursor or Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Currently I am trying to convert vertical data structure to horizontal data dynamically by implementing a cursor in the stored procedure. However, the execution time takes too long. I am trying to find a way to optimise this approach. What is the better way to use other than Cursor? Note: PIVOT cant be used because of scattered data mapping. This is my current code with sample data and expected output:

What I have done so far: There are three temporary tables #tablestructure, #raw and #dsid. #Tablestruture contains all the columns under destfieldname which are needed to create a table. Then once it is created, we need to take the contents from #raw and insert it into the new table which has been created based on the row and column number

#tablestructure

| desttablename | destfieldname | datatype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * | subjectnumber | int |
| sample | personame | nvarchar(20) |
| sample | personlocation | nvarchar(20) |

#raw table

| rownumber | columnnumber | fieldname | contents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | subjectnumber | 132516352 |
| 1 | 2 | personname | Alex |
| 2 | 1 | subjectnumber | 132516353 |
| 2 | 3 | personlocation | Canada |
| 1 | 3 | personlocation | Australia |
| 2 | 2 | personname | John |

#DSID Table

| projectid | respondentfieldname | debug | fileincludedheaders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | subjectnumber | NULL | 1 |

Expected output

| Subjectnumber | PersonName | Personlocation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 132516352 | Alex | Australia |
| 132516353 | John | Canada |

```
declare createSQL cursor for 
select distinct 'drop table TestTmp.dbo.' + t.destname  as droptableSQL,
         'CREATE TABLE TestTmp.dbo.' + t.destname    + ' (' + stuff((
            select ',[' + destfieldname + '] ' + f.datatype from #tableStructure f 
            where (f.desttablename in (t.desttablename, '*')) 
            group by destfieldname, f.datatype) 
    for xml path ('')),1,1,'') + ', [sequenceID] int, [subsequenceID] int)'  as createTableSQL,
'insert into VectorNormalizerTmp.dbo.' + t.desttablename + @tablesuffix + '([' + replace(replace(respondentidfieldname,']',''),'[','') + '],sequenceid, subsequenceid) 
SELECT a.contents, b.sequenceid, b.subsequenceid from (select contents from #raw where fieldname = ''' + respondentidfieldname + ''') a 
CROSS JOIN (select sequenceid, subsequenceid from #rowUniques where desttablename = ''' + desttablename +''') b ' as appendEmptyRowsSQL,
'create index idx' + t.desttablename + @tablesuffix + ' on VectorNormalizerTmp.dbo.' + desttablename + @tablesuffix + '([' + respondentidfieldname + '],sequenceid, subsequenceid)' as idxSQL

from (select distinct desttablename from #tablestructure where desttablename = 'Screener') t
cross join (select respondentidfieldname, debug from #dsid) d


declare @sqltorun nvarchar(max);
declare @sqltorun2 nvarchar(max);
declare @sqltorun3 nvarchar(max);
declare @sqltorun4 nvarchar(max);

open createSQL
fetch next from createSQL into @sqltorun, @sqltorun2, @sqltorun3, @sqltorun4
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
begin
    begin try
    --print @sqltorun
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltorun
    end try
    begin catch
    --print '!!ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()   
    end catch
    print @sqltorun2
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltorun2
    print @sqltorun3
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltorun3
    --print @sqltorun4
    begin try
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltorun4
    end try
    begin catch
    --print '!!ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()   
    end catch
    fetch next from createSQL into @sqltorun, @sqltorun2, @sqltorun3, @sqltorun4
end
close createSQL
deallocate createSQL
```

Comment: This really feels like the fundament problem is the design if I am honest.

Comment: What does `*` represent in your column `desttablename`? You can't do `SELECT subjectnumber FROM *`. Do you actually have a table called `*`? I *hope* not.

Comment: its actually a table name

Comment: So you want to create 2 tables, one called `*` and the other `sample`? I strongly suggest you rethink the same of a table called `*`.

Comment: its already created and i cant remove it. So its like i m taking that two tables and join in together

Comment: `columnnumber` is stored in  `#raw table` . Why? I don't see any usage in your script.

Comment: So what is the `JOIN` criteria between the table `*` and `sample`? What happens if 2 tables have the same column name?

Comment: *"ts already created and i cant remove it. "* so you just need to `INSERT` the data into your tables? Then you can just write the query `SELECT star.Subjectnumber, s.PersonName, s.Personlocation FROM dbo.[*] star JOIN dbo.sample s ON {Expression(s)};`?

Comment: i am trying to get the table structure and use the raw data to map into a new table with horizontal structure

Comment: i need to insert the contents based on column number and row number from #raw

Comment: basically i need to create a table from fieldname column in #tablestructure and take the data from #raw, insert it into the new table

Comment: *" i need to create a table"* conflicts with *"its already created"* If you need to create the table, it can't already be created... I think you need to take a step back and [edit] your question to ***explain*** the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247985/discussion-between-sriram-and-larnu).

Comment: As I said, [edit] your question; I don't enter chats I'm afraid (my experience is it turns into consultancy, and that's not why I'm here).

Comment: So, TL;DR: You want to create 2 tables, `*`, and `sample`, with the columns from `tablestructure`, and then you want to `INSERT` the data from `raw` into the respective columns in the 2 created tables?

Comment: no u can ignore the * and sample because its the table name from other table which are not needed. Just need to take the destfieldname from #tablestructure and construct a new table then insert the data from raw

Comment: i dont want to use cursor because its taking a lot of time to construct the table and also inserting the data

Comment: @Sriram there's no such thing as horizontal or vertical table structures. The "Raw table" is anything but - it's an ugly *anti*-pattern called the Entity-Attribute-Value. It's an attempt to store "dynamic" data instead of providing proper fields. As you found out, it's impossible to query, index or check such values. It's also completely redundant since 2005, when sparse columns and the XML data type were added. You can have 32000 sparse columns in a table. There's no need for EAV

Comment: So you just want to create the table `sample` with the columns `PersonName` and `personlocation`? Why is `Subjectnumber` in your expected output then?

Comment: @Larnu yes a table with Subjectnumber, PersonName, Personlocation and insert the data from raw into respective columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ya this is why i am not sure what approach to use so that i can create a new table and insert all those values

Comment: @Larnu as u can see, subjectnumber is also a column name under destfieldname in #tablestructure

Comment: But it's *not* a column in the table `sample`... It's part of a table poorly named `*`.

Comment: ya actually its from another table. But i have joined it before that. Plus i want to create a new table. Not sample table. Sample table is just reference for the columns: personname and personlocation

Comment: Also in one table you have `personame` and in the other `personname`; is that intentional?

Comment: because it was created to do the mapping. As u can see, tablestructure have only the fieldname and datatype. I have done the join in select query when i create the table. Cross join

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this question is unclear, I've guessed what you are after, as it was never truly explained. This creates your 2 tables, `*` and `sample` (on a hard coded schema `dbo`) and `INSERT`s the data from table `raw` into the respective tables. It also assumes you are on a fully supported version of SQL Server.

This is, however, a complete mess:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.tablestructure
FROM (VALUES(N'*',N'subjectnumber',N'int'),
            (N'sample',N'personname',N'nvarchar(20)'),
            (N'sample',N'personlocation',N'nvarchar(20)'))V(desttablename,destfieldname,datatype);

SELECT *
INTO dbo.raw
FROM (VALUES(1,1,N'subjectnumber',N'132516352'),
            (1,2,N'personname',N'Alex'),
            (2,1,N'subjectnumber',N'132516353'),
            (2,3,N'personlocation',N'Canada'),
            (1,3,N'personlocation',N'Australia'),
            (2,2,N'personname',N'John'))V(rownumber,columnnumber,fieldname,contents);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

WITH Tables AS(
    SELECT ts.desttablename,
           N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(ts.desttablename) + N' (' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(ts.destfieldname) + N' ' + QUOTENAME(V.datatype) + V.precisionscale,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ts.destfieldname) + N');' AS CreateStatement
    FROM dbo.tablestructure ts
         --I don't trust data in a table like this, so I'm going to check it's "good"
         --This won't cause an error it's it's bad, but it'll always avoid injection
         --If you want an error, you would need to checl the validity first
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEFT(ts.datatype,CHARINDEX('(',datatype+'(')-1),STUFF(ts.datatype,1,CHARINDEX('(',datatype+'(')-1,'')))V(datatype,precisionscale)
         JOIN sys.types t ON V.datatype = t.name --Make sure that the datatype is valid
    WHERE V.precisionscale NOT LIKE '%[^(),0-9 ]%' --Only contains parenthesis, numbers, commas and spaces
       OR V.precisionscale = '(MAX)' --Or the scale is MAX
    GROUP BY ts.desttablename)
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(CreateStatement,@CRLF) 
FROM Tables T;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL; 
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

WITH InsertClause AS (
    SELECT ts.desttablename,
           N'INSERT INTO dbo.' + QUOTENAME(desttablename) + N' (' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(destfieldname) + N'',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY destfieldname) + N')' AS InsertClause
    FROM dbo.tablestructure ts
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.raw r
                  WHERE ts.destfieldname = r.fieldname)
    GROUP BY ts.desttablename),
RowValues AS(
    SELECT IC.InsertClause,
           N'(' + STRING_AGG(N'N''' + REPLACE(r.contents,'''','''''') + N'''',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.fieldname) + N')' AS RowInsert
    FROM InsertClause IC
         JOIN dbo.tablestructure ts ON IC.desttablename = ts.desttablename
         JOIN dbo.raw r ON ts.destfieldname = r.fieldname
    GROUP BY IC.InsertClause,
             r.rownumber),
InsertStatements AS(
    SELECT InsertClause + @CRLF +
           N'VALUES ' + STRING_AGG(RowInsert,N',') + N';' AS FullInsertStatement
    FROM RowValues
    GROUP BY InsertClause)
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(FullInsertStatement,@CRLF)
FROM InsertStatements;

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.[*];

SELECT *
FROm dbo.[sample];

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.tablestructure;
DROP TABLe dbo.raw;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.[*]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.sample;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/psZvw8Ze)